# How to test redirection to an external URL?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, testing, ruby-on-rails-3.2, http-redirect

I am using [rack-rewrite](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite) to redirect legacy URLs. The old paths that redirect to new internal paths, I can test just fine, like this:

```
require 'test_helper'

class MiscellaneousTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

    test 'redirect about.php' do
        get_via_redirect '/about.php?country=US'
        assert_equal '/us/about', path

        get_via_redirect '/about.php?country=CA'
        assert_equal '/ca/about', path

        # default
        get_via_redirect '/about.php'
        assert_equal '/ca/about', path
    end
end
```

But what I am wondering is: how can I test cases where an old path now maps to an external URL?

For example, if the following old route is detected: `/blog/12345/something-cool-to-say` it will now map to the following external URL: `http://blog.far.far.away.com/12345/something-cool-to-say` via:

```
$BLOG_URL = 'http://blog.far.far.away-example.com'
r301 %r{^/blog/([0-9]{5})/(.*)\.php}, "#{BLOG_URL}/$1/$2" # token, slug
```

Comment: Hi, did you manage to test routing to an external URL?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
assert_redirected_to 'http://some.host/with/a/path'
```